# How to change photoshop color channels with script

Tags: javascript, photoshop, channel

I want to create a script to run in photoshop and adjust the channels. My goal is to take a known color, example 0,0,255(blue), and change it to yellow, or red, or green, etc.

What I'd like to do is create a function that does this. 
What I've got so far

```
    function changeChannel()
{
var sColor = new SolidColor(); 
var chDesc = new ActionDescriptor ;//channel descriptor 
var cdesc = new ActionDescriptor ;// color descriptor 

cdesc.putDouble(charIDToTypeID("Rd  "),sColor.rgb.red);
...
execute(charIDToTypeID("ChnM"),...No idea)
```

I have no idea where to go after this.